# Why is gradle build failed every time when I run my app on my actual device in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, adb

```
[androidstudio1][1]
```

I am following the docs "start another activity" on Android Developers. When I connect my device (Huawei KNT-AL20 with Android 8.0.0) to android studio, it showed it was connected, but Gradle build always failed except the first time (as shown in the graph). I really want to know what the problem is.

In addition, why is "@string/app_name" in AndroidManifest.xml remained "cannot resolve" even I invalidated caches and restart?

[@string/app_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odHlj.png)

Answer (score -1):

1. check if your app is running on emulator.
2. If app is running fine on emulator, try changing your cable. Some times due to poor connectivity gradle build fails.

Comment: But my emulator (Pixel 2 XL API 26) doesn't work, either. It needs hardware acceleration.